# How can I use a recursive method of changing all adjacent elements in a 2D list?

Tags: python, list, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a little game and I'm having trouble getting it to work the way I need it to. I need to find a way (I'm guessing recursively?) to mutate a 2D list such that all adjacent characters are replaced with a different character. For example, if I have a 2D list like this:

> [['#', '#', '#', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%'], ['#', '#', '@', '@',
>   '&', '&', '&', '#', '%'], ['@', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '&', '#',
>   '%'], ['@', '@', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%', '%'], ['#', '@', '%',
>   '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%']]

It should print in a grid that looks like this:

```
   012345678
0  $$$@@$$$%
1  $$@@&&&$% 
2  @$$$$$&$%
3  @@@@$$$%%
4  $@%%%%%%%
```

If the user enters a "%" at row 3 column 1 for instance, every "@" connected to each other should change into the desired symbol so that it becomes:

```
   012345678
0  $$$@@$$$%
1  $$@@&&&$% 
2  %$$$$$&$%
3  %%%%$$$%%
4  $%%%%%%%%
```

The goal would be to get everything to be the same symbol. My function to fill these spaces currently looks like the following, and is only replacing a symbol at the desired location and nothing adjacent to it:

```
def fill(gameBoard, targetSymbol, userSymbol, row, col):

    if gameBoard[row][col] != targetSymbol:
        pass
    elif gameBoard[row][col] == targetSymbol:
        gameBoard[row][col] = userSymbol
```

I know this is a bit bare-bones at the moment but most of what I've tried has ended up not working. What would be the best way to get it to also change the adjacent spots? I'm assuming recursion is best but I haven't really done much with recursion yet and I'm struggling to figure out the logic behind getting it to work.

Comment: why you would not edit your question , and make it look as a question ? for example , starting with how do I ... and ending with a question mark?

Comment: Quick reminder, solutions to homework problems that were lifted directly from stackoverflow are worth zero marks (or worse).

Answer (score 0):

This is very crude, recursive way of filling the matrix at selected positions. It can be definitely written shorter, but at least it's something to start:

```
matrix = [['#', '#', '#', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%'],
          ['#', '#', '@', '@', '&', '&', '&', '#', '%'],
          ['@', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '&', '#', '%'],
          ['@', '@', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%', '%'],
          ['#', '@', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%']]

def _fill(data, x, y, ch, orig=None, seen=None):
    if orig is None:
        orig = data.get((x, y), None)

    if seen is None:
        seen = set()

    #fill up
    if (x, y-1) in data and (x, y-1) not in seen and data.get((x, y-1), None) == orig:
        seen.add((x, y-1))
        _fill(data, x, y-1, ch, orig, seen)
        data[(x, y-1)] = ch

    #fill down
    if (x, y+1) in data and (x, y+1) not in seen and data.get((x, y+1), None) == orig:
        seen.add((x, y+1))
        _fill(data, x, y+1, ch, orig, seen)
        data[(x, y+1)] = ch

    #fill left
    if (x-1, y) in data and (x-1, y) not in seen and data.get((x-1, y), None) == orig:
        seen.add((x-1, y))
        _fill(data, x-1, y, ch, orig, seen)
        data[(x-1, y)] = ch

    #fill right
    if (x+1, y) in data and (x+1, y) not in seen and data.get((x+1, y), None) == orig:
        seen.add((x+1, y))
        _fill(data, x+1, y, ch, orig, seen)
        data[(x+1, y)] = ch

def fill(matrix, x, y, ch):
    d = {}
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        for j, data in enumerate(row):
            d[(i, j)] = data

    _fill(d, x, y, ch)

    rv = []
    for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
        rv.append([])
        for j, data in enumerate(row):
            rv[-1].append(d[(i, j)])

    return rv

from pprint import pprint
print('Old matrix:')
pprint(matrix)
print('-' * 80)
print()
print('Filled matrix:')
matrix = fill(matrix, 3, 1, '%')
pprint(matrix)
```

Prints:

```
Old matrix:
[['#', '#', '#', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%'],
 ['#', '#', '@', '@', '&', '&', '&', '#', '%'],
 ['@', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '&', '#', '%'],
 ['@', '@', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%', '%'],
 ['#', '@', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%']]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Filled matrix:
[['#', '#', '#', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%'],
 ['#', '#', '@', '@', '&', '&', '&', '#', '%'],
 ['%', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '&', '#', '%'],
 ['%', '%', '%', '%', '#', '#', '#', '%', '%'],
 ['#', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, recursion is a possible solution. Here is my approach. I have used numpy for simplicity but should be similar with python lists.

```py
import numpy as np

table = np.array([['#', '#', '#', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%'],
                  ['#', '#', '@', '@', '&', '&', '&', '#', '%'],
                  ['@', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '&', '#', '%'],
                  ['@', '@', '@', '@', '#', '#', '#', '%', '%'],
                  ['#', '@', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%', '%']])
print('original:')
print(table)

def fill(gameBoard, i, j, symbol):
    if gameBoard[i, j] != symbol:
        originalSymbol = gameBoard[i, j]
        def r(i, j):
            if i < 0 or i >= gameBoard.shape[0] or j < 0 or j >= gameBoard.shape[1]:
                # out of bounds
                return
            #change symbol if it is adjacent
            if gameBoard[i,j] == originalSymbol:
                gameBoard[i,j] = symbol
                for di, dj in [(0, 1), (0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0)]:
                    r(i+di, j+dj)
        r(i, j)
    return gameBoard

print('modified:')
print(fill(table, 3, 1, '%'))
```

output:

```
original:
[['#' '#' '#' '@' '@' '#' '#' '#' '%']
 ['#' '#' '@' '@' '&' '&' '&' '#' '%']
 ['@' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '&' '#' '%']
 ['@' '@' '@' '@' '#' '#' '#' '%' '%']
 ['#' '@' '%' '%' '%' '%' '%' '%' '%']]
modified:
[['#' '#' '#' '@' '@' '#' '#' '#' '%']
 ['#' '#' '@' '@' '&' '&' '&' '#' '%']
 ['%' '#' '#' '#' '#' '#' '&' '#' '%']
 ['%' '%' '%' '%' '#' '#' '#' '%' '%']
 ['#' '%' '%' '%' '%' '%' '%' '%' '%']]
```

Answer (score 0):

No imports:

```py
def fill(board, strT, strS, intR, intC):
    if (intR < len(board) and intC < len(board[0]) and strT == board[intR][intC] and strT != strS):
        board[intR][intC] = strS # Replace the symbol at the current coordinates
        fill(board, strT, strS, intR + 1, intC) # Search down
        fill(board, strT, strS, intR - 1, intC) # Search up
        fill(board, strT, strS, intR, intC + 1) # Search right
        fill(board, strT, strS, intR, intC - 1) # Search left
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this, but from your responses, it seems like that's not what you're looking for. What does the rest of the code for your game look like? I can't know exactly what you need without context. The other user recommended this for the fill function, but I can see how this likely wouldn't be useful for you. So when you edit your comment, you can comment below this. I'll be able to answer it better then.

```
if seen is None:
    seen = set()

#fill up
if (x, y-1) in data and (x, y-1) not in seen and data.get((x, y-1), None) == orig:
    seen.add((x, y-1))
    _fill(data, x, y-1, ch, orig, seen)
    data[(x, y-1)] = ch

#fill down
if (x, y+1) in data and (x, y+1) not in seen and data.get((x, y+1), None) == orig:
    seen.add((x, y+1))
    _fill(data, x, y+1, ch, orig, seen)
    data[(x, y+1)] = ch

#fill left
if (x-1, y) in data and (x-1, y) not in seen and data.get((x-1, y), None) == orig:
    seen.add((x-1, y))
    _fill(data, x-1, y, ch, orig, seen)
    data[(x-1, y)] = ch

#fill right
if (x+1, y) in data and (x+1, y) not in seen and data.get((x+1, y), None) == orig:
    seen.add((x+1, y))
    _fill(data, x+1, y, ch, orig, seen)
    data[(x+1, y)] = ch
```